# Type Safe Redux Reducer with Arguments

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm trying to use typescript with react-redux, I'm having some issues with the reducer. With the current setup I'm getting errors but I can't figure out why it's the case. If I deviate from the approach in the redux documentation I am able to get something that works but it's repetitive.

**----- CODE: -----**

I have three files in three separate directories which resemble:

```
store
|_actions
|   |_auth.ts  
|_reducers
|   |_auth.ts
|_types
    |_actionTypes.ts
    |_auth.ts
```

within `actions/auth.ts` file:

```
// actions/auth.ts
import { AuthActionTypes } from '../types/auth';
import * as actionTypes from '../types/actionTypes';

export const authStart = (): AuthActionTypes => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.AUTH_START
    };
};

export const authSuccess = ( token: string, userId: string ): AuthActionTypes => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.AUTH_SUCCESS,
        idToken: token,
        userId: userId
    };
};

export const authFail = ( error: Error ): AuthActionTypes => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.AUTH_FAIL,
        error: error
    };
};
```

the `reducers/auth.ts` file:

```
// reducers/auth.ts
import * as actionTypes from '../types/actionTypes';
import { AuthState, AuthActionTypes } from '../types/auth';
import { updateObject } from '../utility';

const initialState: AuthState = {
    token: null,
    userId: null,
    error: null,
    loading: false,
    authRedirectPath: '/'
};

const authStart = ( state: AuthState, action: AuthActionTypes ) => {
    return updateObject( state, {error: null, loading: true })
};

const authSuccess = ( state: AuthState, action: AuthActionTypes ) => {
    return updateObject( state, { 
        token: action.idToken, // ##### this is giving me an error #####
        userId: action.userId, // ##### this is giving me an error #####
        error: null,
        loading: false
    });
};

const authFail = ( state: AuthState, action: AuthActionTypes ) => {
    return updateObject( state, {
        error: action.error, // ##### this is giving me an error #####
        loading: false
    });
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action: AuthActionTypes): AuthState => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.AUTH_START: return authStart( state, action );
        case actionTypes.AUTH_SUCCESS: return authSuccess( state, action );
        case actionTypes.AUTH_FAIL: return authFail( state, action );
        default: 
            return state;
    };
};

export default reducer;
```

the `types/auth.ts` file:

```
// types/auth.ts
import * as actionTypes from './actionTypes';

export interface AuthState {
    token: null | string
    userId: null | string
    error: null | Error
    loading: boolean
    authRedirectPath: string
} 

interface AuthStart {
    type: typeof actionTypes.AUTH_START
}

interface AuthSuccess {
    type: typeof actionTypes.AUTH_SUCCESS;
    idToken: string;
    userId: string;
}

interface AuthFail {
    type: typeof actionTypes.AUTH_FAIL;
    error: Error;
}

export type AuthActionTypes = 
| AuthStart 
| AuthSuccess
| AuthFail;
```

for completeness the `updateObject` function found in `utility.ts` file used in `reducers/auth.ts`

```
export const updateObject = <T, U>(oldObject: T, updatedProperties: U): T => {
    return {
        ...oldObject,
        ...updatedProperties
    };
};
```

**----- PROBLEM: -----**

Within `reducers/auth.ts` the problem lies with the `authSuccess` arrow function. I am presented with the following error message:

```
Property 'idToken' does not exist on type 'AuthActionTypes'.
Property 'idToken' does not exist on type 'AuthStart'.
```

We can see that both `idToken` and `userId` are defined in the `interface`. I don't see why it would be referencing `AuthStart` and not `AuthSuccess`. If I export the `AuthSucess` interface and declare it as the action type for that function then the error message is gone. Is there any way of keeping `action` as `AuthActionType` or does it need to be explicitly declared as `AuthSucess` and the same for the others with this setup?

Additionaly if I remove all the arrow functions and defined the logic directly in the case the error is no longer there. That is if I have

```
// reducers/auth.ts
...
const reducer = (state = initialState, action: AuthActionTypes): AuthState => {
    switch (action.type) {
        ...
        case actionTypes.AUTH_SUCCESS: 
            return { 
               ...state, 
               token: action.idToken, 
               userId: action.userId, 
               error: null,
             };
...
```

Is there any way of keeping the setup that I have now without having to but the above logic directly in the swtich case, since the solution I have is easier for me to maintain?

Comment: clearly tells, you don't have interface with property like idToken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the definition of the `AuthSuccess` function on its own:

```
const authSuccess = ( state: AuthState, action: AuthActionTypes ) => {
    return updateObject( state, { 
        token: action.idToken, // ##### this is giving me an error #####
        userId: action.userId, // ##### this is giving me an error #####
        error: null,
        loading: false
    });
};
```

This definition suggests that `action` can be any of the `AuthActionTypes`, including `AuthStart` which lacks the `idToken` property. Instead type the function as

```
const authSuccess = ( state: AuthState, action: AuthSuccess ) => {
    return updateObject( state, { 
        token: action.idToken, // ##### this is giving me an error #####
        userId: action.userId, // ##### this is giving me an error #####
        error: null,
        loading: false
    });
};
```

The `switch` statement in your reducer will allow typescript to refine the type of `action` passed to `authSuccess` as only `AuthSuccess` and not one of the other `AuthActionTypes`.

This is the reason why inlining these functions works fine - the complier knows the action must be of type `AuthSuccess` in the `case` block so `idToken` and `userId` are valid.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the accepted answer, we would specifically recommend that you switch to using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org).  It ncludes utilities to simplify several common Redux use cases, including store setup, defining reducers, immutable update logic, and even creating entire "slices" of state at once.  It's also already written in TypeScript, and will minimize the number of type declarations you have to write.

Looking at your example, use of `createSlice` would probably eliminate half the code you've got there, and reduce it down to a single file.